# Teradata Parsing Full Name field sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column with a name value with a data type of char(64) LATIN in a Teradata table.  The values look like 'SMITH       JOHN J     ', 'Doe    Jane   Anne    ', etc.  The spaces between the elements vary from value to value.  I am able to parse out the last name out with a left, but I am having trouble parsing out the first name and middle initial/name.  I have tried using the index and position functions, but I am not getting the desired result.  Has anyone encountered a similar scenario?

Comment: Have a look at the `strtok` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `regexp_substr()` and adjust the `occurence` argument, which specifies the number of the occurence to return:

```
select 
    regexp_substr(name, '\w+', 1, 1) last_name,
    regexp_substr(name, '\w+', 1, 2) middle_name,
    regexp_substr(name, '\w+', 1, 3) first_name
from mytable
```

In PCRE notation, which Teradata used, `\w` matches on word characters (alphanumeric and the underscore). You might want to make the regex a little broader with `\S` (anything *but* a space).

Comment: Thank you.  This function solved my problem easily.

Comment: Hopefully there's no hyphenated name or a `O'Hara` or comma instead of space. `StrTok(name, ' ,', 1)` is much simpler in this case